# How to run background service in flutter

Tags: flutter, background-task

I am trying to develop a flutter app which will fetch data from server every 10 seconds using timer. It all works well when in foreground. So I followed the documentation provided here [Work Manager](https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager)  and I can get the data from server even when app is in background but cannot reduce the frequency below 15 minutes. I dont want to code in native android and ios. How can I approach this situation ? Is there a solution I am missing ?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NXuAzXY_KOo) about background job processing